# Does there exist runPercentRank like runFun (runMin, runMax,...) in TTR or how to write one?

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for percent rank function in R but can not find it.

Actually I am interested in runPercentRank function like the ones in `TTR` package under runFun (`runMin`, `runMax`,...). The function would take an `xts` object as argument and length of interval and return an `xts` object with percent ranks of values.

Does something like that exists? Any hints on how to efficiently write such a function?

Comment: Percent ranks? You mean quantiles? Or do you want to have the ranks of the rows of your xts object ? Please give us an example of what exactly you're after. Because as I interprete it, rollapply should be the function you're looking for.

Comment: I can't see how running percent ranks would work. A rank normally has the same number of outputs as inputs, unlike min, mean, max, etc.

Comment: Hello. I guess I found something similar here https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/DVI.R?view=markup&revision=106&root=ttr . # A simple percent rank function, possibly different
  # than Excel's percentrank function.
  pctRank <- function(x,i) match(x[i], sort(coredata(x[(i-(n-1)):i])))

  # calculate the DVI magnitude and stretch for each period
  dvi.mag <- dvi.str <- rep(NA,NROW(price))
  for(i in n:NROW(price)) {
    dvi.mag[i] <- pctRank(mag, i) / n
    dvi.str[i] <- pctRank(str, i) / n
  } Is it possible to avoid this for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Charlie Friedemann, there is now an extremely fast `runPercentRank` function in TTR >= 0.22.0.

```
library(quantmod)
data(ttrc)
pr <- runPercentRank(Cl(ttrc))
plot(pr, type="l")
```

Comment: Great! Will you please export it?  :-D